# Admob native ads positioning in recyclerview android formula

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob

I was able to successfully populate items and admob native ads together into the recyclerview but the formula that I used that is `(position % 4 == 0)` for when to show the ads is not what the outcome I wanted it to be

It puts the native ad items at position 0 and after every 4 items.

What I would like is to show the first two items, followed by an ad item and every after 4 items to show an ad item

Below is an image of what I want it to look like

[image: id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(position % 4) == offset`, where offset = 2 in your case should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

also check that your position is not zero

```
if (position % 4 == 0 && position != 0) {
//Your Ads
..
}
```